# Vb.net condition last digit check

Tags: vb.net, linq

RuGroup will be containing like this...

MA1,MA2,MA3,MA4,MA5,MA6,MA7,MA8,MA9

I've checked MA and the length. How can I check if 3rd digit is a number? cuz if value is stored as MAS, I need to display that. Please let me know how to use EndsWith property or something else in this..

```
getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where Not (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3)).ToList()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I used this.

```
If CBool(IIf(cboCountrySpec.SelectedValue.Equals(PIAConstants.CountrySpecOne), True, False)) OrElse _
                CBool(IIf(cboCountrySpec.SelectedValue.Equals(PIAConstants.CountrySpecTwo), True, False)) Then
                'getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where Not retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Contains("MA")).ToList()                
                getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where Not (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3 And ((retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("1")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("2")) Or
                (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("3")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("4")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("5")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("6")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("7")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("8")) Or
                (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("9"))))) 'IKEA00879697
            Else
                'getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Contains("MA")).ToList()                
                getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3 And ((retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("1")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("2")) Or
                (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("3")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("4")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("5")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("6")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("7")) Or (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("8")) Or
                (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.EndsWith("9"))))) 'IKEA00879697
            End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Char.IsDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim invalids = From rug in RetailUnits 
               Where rug.RuGroupName.Length < 3 _
                 OrElse Not rug.RuGroupName.StartsWith("MA") _
                 OrElse Not Char.IsDigit(rug.RuGroupName(2))
```

Comment: Nice `Linq` solution!

Answer (score 1):

OK, well try someting like this.... it's winform code. Create a new winforms application and put 2 ComboBox controls on the form, then copy\paste the code below...

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Dim RetailUnits As New List(Of RetailUnit)

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
    Dim getRetailUgrp1 As New List(Of RetailUnit)
    Dim regex1 As Regex = New Regex("")
    If DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox).SelectedItem < 3 Then
        regex1 = New Regex("^([A-Z]{2,3})+$")
    Else
        regex1 = New Regex("^([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1})+$")
    End If
    Try
        ComboBox2.DataSource = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString = regex1.Match(retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString).Value)).ToList()
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "RuGroupName"
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA1"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA2"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA3"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA4"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA5"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA6"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA7"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA8"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA9"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "AU"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "AUW"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "AS"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MA"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MAR"})
    RetailUnits.Add(New RetailUnit With {.RuGroupName = "MAS"})

    Dim ComboBox1Items() As String = New String() {"1", "2", "3"}
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(ComboBox1Items)
End Sub
End Class


Class RetailUnit
Private _RuGroupName As String
Public Property RuGroupName() As String
    Get
        Return _RuGroupName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _RuGroupName = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: My data is
AU, AUW, AS, MA, MA1, MA2, MA3, MA4, MA5, MA6, MA7, MA8, MA9, MAR, MAS

In if condition, I need to display AU, AUW, AS, MA, MAR, MAS
and in else condition I need to display only MA1, MA2, MA3, MA4, MA5, MA6, MA7, MA8, MA9

Comment: The below condition misses MAR and MAS. 

If CBool(IIf(cboCountrySpec.SelectedValue.Equals(PIAConstants.CountrySpecOne), True, False)) OrElse _
CBool(IIf(cboCountrySpec.SelectedValue.Equals(PIAConstants.CountrySpecTwo), True, False)) Then

getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where Not (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3)).ToList() 
Else
getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3).ToList() 
End If

Comment: Index out of bound of array if I include char.Isdigit.. getRetailUgrp = (From retailUnitGrp In RetailUnits Where Not (retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.StartsWith("MA") And retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName.ToString.Length = 3 And Char.IsDigit(retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName(3)))).ToList()

Comment: In Linq, I need to check as - if both starts with MA and length condition is 3 then append AND condition of Char.IsDigit(3rd character)

Comment: No. I'm still looking for the answer..
DB contains many values like AU, AUW, MA1, MA2, MA3, MA4,.....MA9, MAR, MAS.
In frontend, I've 2 dropdowns...In 1st dropdown values are 1,2,3. In 2nd dropdown values fetched based on 1st dropdown.

If 1st dropdown value is 3, then constantly I need to display only 'MA1 to MA9 alone' and nothing else. If 1st dropdown value is 1 or 2, I need to display everything other than 'MA1 to MA9'

That's why I tried the conditions startswith and length. However if db has value as MAR or MAS or anything, it won't display in 2nd dropdown when 1st dropdown value=1 or 2

Comment: Hope now everyone understood what I need.. Plz check the code Naraykln Feb 9 at 5:36

Comment: Naraykln :: I have modified my answer... again..... Hope that helps you out... Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that each component is at least three characters long, you can do the following in C# (which should translate directly to VB.Net)

```
Char.IsDigit(retailUnitGrp.RuGroupName[2])
```

That will return true of the third digit (0-based index) is a number.